# How do I compare two arrays of strings made from strdup() in C?

Tags: arrays, c, string

I'm wondering how do I compare two *arrays of strings* in C.

This is my code (not working properly when comparing):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char *splitted1[64];
    char *splitted2[64];
    int w1 = 0, w2 = 0;

    char ph1[64];
    fgets(ph1, 64, stdin);
    strtok(ph1, "\n");

    char ph2[64];
    fgets(ph2, 64, stdin);
    strtok(ph2, "\n");

    char spl[] = " ";
    char *ptr1 = strtok(ph1, spl);
    while (ptr1 != NULL) {
        splitted1[w1] = strdup(ptr1);
        ptr1 = strtok(NULL, spl);
        w1++;
    }
    char *ptr2 = strtok(ph2, spl);
    while (ptr2 != NULL) {
        splitted2[w2] = strdup(ptr2);
        ptr2 = strtok(NULL, spl);
        w2++;
    }

    // HERE I TRY TO COMPARE
    for (int k = 0; k < w1; k++) {
        for (int m = 0; m < w2; m++) {
            if (splitted1[k] == splitted2[m]) {
                printf("%s is on both arrays\n", splitted1[k]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What's wrong with my comparison method?

Thanks in advance and sorry if duplicated (I already search but didn't find a similar case).

EDIT: I didn't have data in `splitted2`. Code already fixed

Comment: Do you want to know whether they are the *same*, or *equal*? Remember that strings are represented by a pointer to their first element.

Comment: @Deduplicator I want to know if they are equal (==), but I'm a bit lost.

Comment: you dont have any data in `splitted2`, so what are you comparing?

Comment: @IrAM Thanks, I just noticed it after reading your comment on the answer below, my mistake, I already fixed it but kept the comparison error I was doing to make this post useful for anyone wondering the same as me.

Comment: Note: `strtok(ph1, "\n");` fails to lop off `'\n'` when `ph1` is only `"\n"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to compare strings with ==. That compares for pointer identity, which is rarely what you want. Try this:

```
if (!strcmp(splitted1[k], splitted2[m]))
```

`strcmp()` is the string comparison function. It returns 0 if they're equal, so you need the !. It's actual job is to return negative, 0, or positive so you can sort strings by byte (if UTF-8 this is also codepoint), but usually you're just comparing for equality these days and using a different function to sort (another topic).

As IrAM points out, your original copy was missing some code and didn't have any data in `splitted2` yet so that would have lead to undefined behavior.